# Идентификаторы в Rust

Tags: json, rust, структуры

Есть JSON, в котором приходит такое значение - 3h:0.0175.
Компилятор ругается на 3h:

```
src/main.rs:97:9: 97:11 error: expected identifier, found `3h`
src/main.rs:97     pub 3h: f64,
```

Как обойти? Сломал мозг....
вот минимальный код:

```
extern crate rest_client;
extern crate rustc_serialize;


use rest_client::RestClient;
use rustc_serialize::json;

use std::env;

#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable, Debug)]
pub struct JsonListSnow {
pub 3h: f64,   //вот собственно....
}

#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable, Debug)]
pub struct JsonList {

pub snow: JsonListSnow, 

}

#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable, Debug)]
pub struct Json {
   pub list: Vec<JsonList>,
}

fn main() {

let  s  = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";

//вектор vr[] получает значения из разбора аргументов командной строки

let req = s.to_string()+&vr[0]+"?q="+&vr[1]+"&units=metric&appid="+&vr[2];

let response = RestClient::get(&req).unwrap();

let decoded: Json = json::decode(&response.body).unwrap();

}
```

Пример JSON:

```
{"city":{"id":2014624,"name":"Udachnyy","coord":  
{"lon":112.400002,"lat":66.416672},"country":"RU","population":0,"sys":
{"population":0}},"cod":"200","message":0.1719,"cnt":35,"list":
[{"dt":1475334000,"main":"temp":277.32,"temp_min":267.745,"temp_max":  
277.32,    "pressure":985.96,"sea_level":1039.29,"grnd_level":985.96,   
 "humidity":89,"temp_kf":9.58},"weather": 
[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light  
snow","icon":"13n"}],"clouds":{"all":76},"wind":
{"speed":1.51,"deg":333.501},"snow":{"3h":0.11},"sys": 
{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2016-10-01 15:00:00"}
```

Comment: Добавьте пример JSON, полный backtrace ошибки и минимальный воспроизводимый пример кода. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Пример JSON добавьте-таки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как имя `3h` является недопустимым для поля структуры (на что и намекает компилятор), то придется вручную реализовать типаж `Decodable` для `JsonListSnow`:

```
use rustc_serialize::Decodable;
use rustc_serialize::Decoder;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct JsonListSnow {
   pub _3h: f64,   
}

impl Decodable for JsonListSnow {
    fn decode<D: Decoder>(d: &mut D) -> Result<JsonListSnow, D::Error> {
        d.read_struct("snow", 1, |d| {
            let _3h = try!(d.read_struct_field("3h", 0, |d| { d.read_f64() }));
            Ok(JsonListSnow{ _3h: _3h })
        })
    }
}
```